# How do I filter the data when there are many conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about python pandas.

For example, the dataset df has 100 rows and the column names are a1, a2, a3, ... , a20. If I want to find  specific rows where a1=20, a2=1, a3=0, a4=1, a5=2,...., a20=1, how can I filter out the rows if such row exists?

If I use pandas filter, how should I set the filter condition? I was thinking using a for-loop to filter based on each condition, in this case I have to filter 20 times. This approach seems very stupid if there are 100 conditions. I wonder if there is any more efficient way.

Comment: You are right, 20 conditions here is not necessary, create dictionary and use some solution from dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[(df['a1'] == 20) & (df['a2'] == 1) & (df['a3'] == 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are many conditions, thay can be added step by step to form filter expression:

```
filter = df['a1'] == 20
filter = filter & (df['a2'] == 1)
...
filter = filter & (df['a20'] == 1)
df = df[filter]
```